# Copy data validation "list of items" from one sheet to another?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, data-validation

On one sheet I have a column that uses "list of items" data validation which allows for a drop-down menu to extend and a multiple of options to be selected.

Is there a way to automatically populate the same relative column in sheet two with the items selected in the column in sheet 1?

For example, if "Dogs" is selected in Sheet1 A1, then it would automatically populate Sheet2 A1 with "Dogs".

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible by single Data Validation. You will either need to create Data Validation rule in Sheet2 or you can mirror the whole sheet/column/cell with one of these:

- sheet: **`={Sheet1!A:Z}`**
- column: **`={Sheet1!A1:A}`**
- cell: **`=Sheet1!A1`**

For a mare copy/paste of Data Validation there is an option:

[image: 0]